# .load() jquery with Servlet

Tags: ajax, servlets, jquery

Is it possible to load the contents in a div through a servlet via .load() jquery ?

I tried this

```
$('#getDetails').load('getDetails');
```

But its not working !! What can be an alternative to this ?

Thanks

Comment: Death?! Seriously have you just tried the URL `getDetails` - of course making it relative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?  If there's one parameter, it must be a URL.  `getDetails` alone apparently isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your servlet has to override method `doGet`, like this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

// implementation

}
```

In the web.xml, you put servlet mapping, like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.myservlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</servlet>
```

Then, you call servlet from JQuery context, like this:

```
function someFunction() {

    $("#yourDivId").load("./servlet");

}
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

got it.

I changed the method of servlet to do get, and passed a parameter with servlet name.

```
$('#getDetails').load('getDetails?process=u');
```

Its working now.

Thanks ..